# xs vs xsd types

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xs:gmonth type that I am working on, so I was looking around to see the valid format for it and I came across 2 definitions:

`xsd:gmonth which accept the format --MM,
xs:gmonth which accept the format --MM--,`

> xs:gmonth format will not be valid for
>   the xsd:gmonth format and oposit is
>   correct

.

Can anybody please tell me what is the difference between the xs: and xsd: types? aren't they both used for XML Schema?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on your xmlns declarations.

Comment: Thanks Martinho,
would you be able to explain more please? I will truly appreciate it...

Comment: Somewhere in that file (probably in the root element) there are attributes like this `xmlns:xs=...` and `xmlns:xsd=...`. The answer to your question depends on those. Can you post them?

Comment: Yes, I do see it where it is declared as xs: or xsd: this clarified what I had the confusion on... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

The `xs:` and `xsd:` are called namespaces. They are declared using `xmlns` elements in the root element.

By convention people tend to choose either `xs:` or `xsd:` and map that to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. Having both in a single document is confusing and should be avoided.

Check your `xmlns` declarations to determine what the namespaces are.